# Refactoring long statement into a reusable function

Tags: c#, function, selenium-webdriver

Currently learning Selenium, using C# and Visual Studio, often you have to wait for a web element to become enabled before it can be interacted with, and as such you use a wait statement similar to:

```
using ec = SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions;
            IWebElement submitPassword = wait.Until(ec.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("submitPassword")));
            submitPassword.Click();
```

It's a lot to type out every single time, so I've tried to shorten it all to a simpler function, so far I have gotten as far as this:

```
        private static IWebElement waitById(WebDriverWait wait, String ElementId)
        {
        return wait.Until(ec.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id(ElementId)));
        }
```

This lets me shorten the above to:

```
 IWebElement passwordField= waitById(wait, "submitPassword");
 passwordField.Click();
```

The method `By.` can be followed by several search types, e.g `By.Name`,`By.ClassName`,`By.XPath` etc.

I'd like my function to accept the search type, so I could do:

```
IWebElement passwordField= waitById(wait,ClassName, "submitPassword");
```

And have it search by ClassName instead of Id, but I can't seem to get my function to accept this as a argument. When I look at the definition of `By`, it looks like each type is its own sub function (apologies if using incorrect terminology), I've tried just putting:

```
        private static IWebElement waitById(WebDriverWait wait,String SearchType, String ElementId)
        {
        return wait.Until(ec.ElementToBeClickable(By.SearchType(ElementId)));
        }
```

But I just get an error saying `By` doesn't contain a definition for SearchType, so I'm not understanding how I pass this argument to that particular method. Googling has gotten me this close but I'm still a bit to green to fully get my head around how to solve this, any help appreciated.

Comment: I think the most elegant would be to have 3 methods `WaitByName`, `WaitByClassName` and `WaitByXPath` and for these methods you would need to pass only the `WebDriverWait` and the value that you want to search.

Comment: It doesn't sound like the question is about refactoring - it's just about whether `By` has a method called `SearchType`. It doesn't. [This](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_By.htm) shows the methods that are available. Do any of these provide what you need?

Comment: I did try ISearchContext and FindElementMethod, but I still get the same message of it not containing a definition. I may well end up going with nextdarius's suggestion of just having different methods for each type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a `By` instance instead of a string. With your approach, you will have to write a method for each of the locator methods (id, xpath, css selector, name, etc.) and then yet another for each wait type (present, visible, clickable) which is going to turn into a LOT of methods. With a `By`, you can have just three methods, one for each wait type. Here's what I would use...

```
public IWebElement WaitForPresence(By locator)
{
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(locator));
}

public IWebElement WaitForVisible(By locator)
{
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(locator));
}

public IWebElement WaitForClickable(By locator)
{
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(locator));
}
```

I removed the `static` keyword because you should generally avoid it if you plan to run your automation in parallel. You can get yourself into trouble and have threads stepping on each other if you aren't careful.

I would avoid passing around an instance of a `WebDriverWait` because it is related to a specific driver instance and will cause problems if you plan to run in parallel.

Comment: Its telling me that the name driver doesn't exist in the current context, the first line of my Main() is ````driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\DriverLocation");````.  Can one class not access a variable in another?

Comment: I moved that line to before my Main method, put public static IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(etc);, and then everything within the class was able to access the variable.  The only thing I don't understand is why those functions can only be access if I change them to be public static, if I put them as just public then I can't seem to access them?

Comment: Should another clueless newbie stumble across this, read about calling non static methods from a static method (e.g my Main). I had to create a instance of my class by doing ````Classname varname = new Classname();````, after which point I was able to access the methods by doing ````varname.WaitForClickable(etc(etc));````.

Comment: It really depends on how you have your project set up. I had a driver created on test setup using NUnit and then pass that driver instance around when instantiating page objects, etc. Sounds like you got it working now? BTW, I changed the driver name in my answer from `_driver` to `driver` just because that's more common. I use `_driver` locally because of ReSharper suggestions.

Comment: I did thanks. I try to find answers myself but often it's trying to figure out the right question to Google in the first place. I have marked your answer as accepted, thanks again for educating me!

Comment: Yeah it really depends on what you are looking for. I generally start my google search with "c# selenium ..." and that helps but it's not always easy finding what you want.